# Convert ionic 3 application to apk

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

> I am new to ionic 3.I have generated the debugging file(debug.apk).
>   What i need to do to get the unsigned apk.

Update 1 -->

[image]

Please help me guys.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: could you put here ionic info

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd, please see update 1

Comment: You can follow this link https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here.

**Option 1: (Paid service)**

Use [**Ionic pro package service**](http://ionicframework.com/products/package).

> Create native apps in the cloud with Ionic Package to get from code to
>   app store with no platform dependencies or complicated build steps.

**Option 2:**

You need to do it manually for each and every platform.Here is the [**official doc for that**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html).