# converstion of Ionic3 application to unsigned.apk

Tags: php, angular, ionic3

[screen shot of genrated debug.apk]

> I have generated debug.apk file successfully with the help of
>   @sampath, but i need to generate unsigned.apk now, what are the steps.

hope you guys help.
thank you.

Comment: You can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035647/1077309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read: [Ionic Deploying](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/)

There you can find every step for production build and signing.

```
ionic cordova run android --prod --release
```

or

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

> This will minify your app’s code as Ionic’s source and also remove any debugging capabilities from the APK. This is generally used when deploying an app to the Google Play Store.

After this, you can sign your apk according to the documentation.